# Find and copy text to paste in next cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to identify text in a column that can be "Regular Season", "Summer Season", "Christmas Season" or "Stat Holidays" then fill that text in the next cells till there is a numeric value in the cell.

I have a fixed column and know the total row count in the column.

Pre
[image: Before problem solution]

Column E has combination of text and numeric values (like 40, 0, 12 in above screenshot).

Post
[image: After the problem solution.]

I want each cell in column E to have one of four values "Regular Season", "Summer Season", "Christmas Season" or "Stat Holidays".

When Excel finds that the value is "Regular Season", it should copy that cell and keep on pasting it till it finds one of other values, i.e "Summer Season", "Christmas Season" or "Stat Holidays". If it finds another value such as "Summer Season", then Excel should not overwrite that, instead copy that cell and start filling next cells with "Summer Season" till it again hits one of those four text values.

Comment: Can you explain the logic a little better? You screen caps don't match the description your give. It would also be useful to see what you have tried so far

Comment: I have edited the post. Let me know if it makes sense now @ cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your data are in column A , you could try this:

```
Dim iArea As Long

With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        For iArea = .Areas.Count To 2 Step -1
            Range(.Areas(iArea - 1).End(xlDown), .Areas(iArea)).Value = .Areas(iArea - 1).End(xlDown).Value
        Next
    End With
    .Range("A1", .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Areas(1)).Value = .Range("A1").Value
End With
```

Comment: Your solution kinda work but lets say if I change the "A" column to "E" in the code then why does it still impacts the column A? BTW I changed all the references of A to E in your code

Comment: Change “With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))” to “With Range("E1", Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)). Since my solution works you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim str As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, y As Long, StartPoint As Long, EndPoint As Long

    'With statement with the sheet1 that i will use
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find last row of column a
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Assign value to end point
        EndPoint = 0
        'Loop from row 1 to lastrow
        For i = 1 To Lastrow
            'Assing value to start point
            StartPoint = 0
            'Check if the cell in not empty,not numeric and i is greater that Endpoint
            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And Not IsNumeric(.Range("A" & i).Value) And i > EndPoint Then
                str = .Range("A" & i).Value
                'Assing value to Start point
                StartPoint = i
                'Loop from i+1 to last row
                For y = i + 1 To Lastrow
                    'Assing value to End point
                    EndPoint = 0
                    'Check if value not empty and is numeric
                    If .Range("A" & y).Value <> "" And IsNumeric(.Range("A" & y).Value) Then
                        'Assing value to End point
                        EndPoint = y
                        'Exit the loop
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next y
                'Import value to range create by the start & end point
                .Range(Cells(StartPoint, 1), Cells(EndPoint, 1)).Value = str

            End If

        Next i

    End With





End Sub
```

Comment: @DisplayName i m experience a very unusual trend last night. i get almost 10 down votes for my answers. Have in mind that my answer are tested, works and the OP provide positive feedback!!!!